# How to set final/const properties in Dart constructor

Tags: dart, constructor, properties, final

I have a class with an immutable property, int id.
How do I pass the value of id to the constructor?

```
class Hey
{
  var val;
  final int id;
  Hey(int id,var val)
  {
    this.id=id;
    this.val=val;
  }
}

void main()
{
  Hey hey=new Hey(0,1);
}
```

> hey.dart:10:10: Error: Setter not found: 'id'.
>       this.id=id;
>            ^^ hey.dart:10:10: Error: The setter 'id' isn't defined for the class 'Hey'.
>    - 'Hey' is from 'hey.dart'. Try correcting the name to the name of an existing setter, or defining a setter or field named 'id'.
>       this.id=id;
>            ^^

I don't think a setter is required for a const or final field property.
The API is not clear on how to handle this.

Answer (score 4):

From the [Dart language tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#final-and-const):

> Note: Instance variables can be `final` but not `const`. Final instance variables must be initialized before the constructor body starts — at the variable declaration, by a constructor parameter, or in the constructor’s [initializer list](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#initializer-list).

And the section on initializer lists says:

> Besides invoking a superclass constructor, you can also initialize instance variables before the constructor body runs. Separate initializers with commas.
>
> ```dart
> // Initializer list sets instance variables before
> // the constructor body runs.
> Point.fromJson(Map<String, num> json)
>     : x = json['x'],
>       y = json['y'] {
>   print('In Point.fromJson(): ($x, $y)');
> }
> ```

So the general way is through initialization lists.

As mentioned above, you also can initialize at variable declaration:

```dart
class Foo {
  final x = 42;
}
```

or can initialize them by a constructor parameter:

```dart
class Foo {
  final x;

  Foo(this.x);
}
```

although those other approaches might not always be applicable.